# stream-client Global thread has died on Spring Boot application shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I create Kafka Streams applications embedded in a Spring Boot application by using the Spring Kafka `StreamBuilderFactoryBean` to configure Kafka Streams. I then autowire a `StreamsBuilder` to set up a Kafka Streams topology:

```java
    @Bean("streamsBuilder")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamBuilderFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = createConfig();
        CleanupConfig cleanupConfig = new CleanupConfig(false, false);
        KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaStreamsConfiguration = new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(config);
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(kafkaStreamsConfiguration, cleanupConfig);
    }
```

and

```java
    @Bean("streamTopology")
    public KStream<Key, Value> configureTopology(
        @Qualifier("streamsBuilder") StreamsBuilder builder) {
        // set up and return topology
    }
```

For applications with an embedded Kafka Streams App that use one or more GlobalKTables the following ERROR logs are consistently produced on shutdown:

`stream-client [xxx] Global thread has died. The streams application or client will now close to ERROR.`

It seems like the Streams App is not stopped gracefully by Spring on application shutdown. Is some configuration or shutdown hook missing to prevent this from happening? I was under the impression that spring-kafka would handle graceful shutdown.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by Mathias Sax on Slack, this is a known bug for Kafka 2.8.0:

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13423 and corresponding Pull Request https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/11455